# 1/4" TRS cross-coupled output with bypass capacitor. Is TRS jack wired for cross-coupled or not?

Tags: decoupling-capacitor, coupling, bypass, bypass-capacitor

I wrote [Alesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alesis) to get the specs on my mix board main out. Here is what their engineers said:

> The main outs are cross-couple, capacitor bypassed, single-ended output, for a TRS jacks.

My cable builder sent me the following chart to pick the correct connectors:

http://www.rane.com/note110.html

I am in need of two 1/4" TRS output (mix board) to RCA input (amp) cables. After looking at the above referenced chart it is obvious I need #12 cable design. However, you will notice that there are two options on #12 for cross-coupled and non cross-coupled (cross-coupled jump shield to ring and non cross-coupled no jumper) of which no one, including my cable builder and Alesis, seems to know the answers to the following questions.....

My questions are:

1. does a bypass capacitor (decoupling capacitor) on a cross-coupled output negate the need for the corresponding 1/4" TRS jacks to be wired for a cross-coupled output?
2. or, is a cross-coupled output always a cross-coupled output regardless of a decoupling capacitor whereby I should have the 1/4" TRS jacks wired for a cross-coupled output?

I assume the answer is number 2 above, but not sure so I am hoping to get confirmation here. And, I understand that either cable will work. However, the cable builder says it always better to get the cables built to match the exact output and input specifications to eliminate potential problems.

Comment: What is the model number for the mixer. What you say Alesis have said doesn't stack up.

Comment: http://www.alesis.com/multimix-4-usb-fx

Answer (score 1):

> The main outs are cross-couple, capacitor bypassed, single-ended output, for a TRS jacks.

Are you sure you got an engineer and not a sales person?  My best guess is that it's **floating** and **AC coupled**.  But you can't have a floating, single-ended output.  [See here.](https://sound-au.com/balance.htm)

- **Floating** means that the average between Hot and Cold can wander wherever it wants to go as defined by the external connections while the difference is tightly controlled to represent the signal.  By tying Cold to Ground, you then cause Hot to act like a single-ended output, but then it's no longer floating.  Or, if you leave Cold unconnected and connect Hot to anything, then Cold will take most of the signal (inverted) leaving very little for Hot.
- **AC coupled** for your purpose means that it will naturally adapt to whatever DC offset there might be in its own output driver or in the receiving equipment.  This is important because speakers and transformers really don't like DC.  This doesn't affect whether it's floating or single-ended or whatever else because the capacitors that do this are big enough to act like plain wires for audio.
- **Single-ended** means that only one wire carries the signal.  Hopefully you can see now why "floating" and "single-ended" are incompatible.
- Bonus, useful soon:

  - **Balanced** means that the two signal wires have equal impedance so that they pick up noise equally.  The noise can then be subtracted out at the receiving end to give a clean signal.  Equal and opposite drivers are not required; in fact, the board in the youth center that I volunteer sound for has a bunch of XLR and TRS outputs that connect Cold to Ground through the same sized resistor that connects Hot to its driver.  As far as noise performance goes, that's still balanced.
  - **dBFS** is a decibel scale that is referenced to the maximum possible level (FS = Full Scale) and is therefore always negative.  0dBFS by definition is just barely not clipping.

Now that we have some definitions, I can now tell you that, unless you have a very *very* low-end board like the one in my small "fun" system at home, then at least the main outs will be balanced, unlike your RCA input.  So you may have some noise issues, gradually becoming a certainty as you increase the length of your cable run.

If your amps are far enough from the board that one operator can't reach both at the same time, then I would strongly recommend using a balanced input for the amps, even if you have to buy different ones.  If they're close, or if you insist on using the unbalanced input anyway, then there are still some solutions:

1. If your output is floating, then your solution #12 should work, connecting Hot to Signal and Cold to Ground, as long as you never exceed -6dBFS.  The reason to apply this new ceiling is because you actually lost that much headroom by making those connections, which is not reflected on the meter(s).
2. If your output is not floating, then I would recommend your #10 instead, connecting Hot to Signal, and Cold to nothing, which allows you to go all the way up to 0dBFS.
3. If you can't determine whether you're in my #1 or #2 and you're okay with spending some money, you can use an audio transformer between Hot and Cold on the primary winding and between Signal and Ground on the secondary, which also allows 0dBFS *and* gives you a balanced receiver if you put it at that end of the cable.  Be aware though, that good audio transformers are expensive!  For example: http://www.jensen-transformers.com/transformers/line-input/

---

One more thing I'll mention even though you didn't but because I've seen it done before by people who don't fully understand: DO NOT run speakers through wire that's designed for microphones!  This may seem obvious, but I've personally seen several cases where a 16-channel snake, for example, was used for 12 channels of mics and 4 speakers.  The amps were next to the board and the speakers were up front, using the 30-ish-gauge wires to push potentially 200 watts through 8 ohms, which comes out to 5 amps...through 30-ish-gauge wires.  Not good!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Alesis assures me the answer is from their engineering and is correct. And, Yes, I'm aware it's balanced outs going to unbalanced ins which is common going from mix boards to mini class D/T amps and makes the proper cable that much more important. Assuming Alesis is correct, would I use the cross-coupled or non cross-coupled version of #12 cable for my system? 

However, it sounds like you're pretty sure Alesis is wrong. Therefore, maybe I should test to see what the outputs really are? What do you think of this protocol?

Comment: http://www.presonus.com/news/articles/balanced-unbalanced

See "Identifying YOur Output Configuration"

Comment: @tayglo: Hmm, I've never talked to Alesis myself but their stuff is usually pretty good, though perhaps a bit under-spec'ed on average to use in a general case.  What kind of board is this?

Comment: Looks like Presonus has it right, but they don't mention your case of interconnects.  I'd be careful shorting stuff though; it'll probably survive, but no guarantees.

Comment: http://www.alesis.com/multimix-4-usb-fx

It's a pretty straight forward board and I can't find any schematics on it whatsoever.

Comment: Great, they want to spam me before they'll hand over the manual.  :-P

Comment: Made a temporary e-mail address, got the manual, and it still doesn't help.  I would try a modified version of Presonus's tests to ensure that I never loaded Hot or Cold with less than 1kohm or so.  (short = 0ohms)  The easiest way to do this is probably to get a 1/4" stereo -> stereo RCA adapter and a dual RCA cable.  Plug the RCA's into two amp channels and the 1/4" stereo plug into one of the main outs.  Set up the speakers so you can easily tell what each one is doing, given potentially the same signal to both.

Comment: @tayglo: Umm, about the commonality of running balanced outs to unbalanced ins of small amps, I do understand that they're often unbalanced only - and my home system has one - but for anything beyond a few feet, you really need a balanced receiver, which will also handle the interconnect problem automatically.

Comment: And yes, I'm pretty sure Alesis is at least partially wrong here.  They're actually one of several companies now owned by InMusic, and having worked in a similar environment in the past, I can say that the level of dysfunction can be quite surprising.

Comment: This is a portable busking system so my DC amps are limited to 12-24v class orT. If I can find a small 12-24v DC amp with balanced ins for a reasonable price I would buy it. I am building it so that everything, including speakers, are in a backpack and all I have is the mixer in my hands. She will be totally wireless too.

Comment: I will try your protocol. But remember I'm a newbie so it's a little confusing. Are you saying follow presonus protocol with your addition? Also, I will call Alesis again tomorrow and start all over with my question to see if i get the same answer;)

Comment: Cool!  Sorry that the lack of proper documentation has made it hard for you.  Yes, follow Presonus's directions using my method of connections instead of theirs so that the output never sees anything more stressful than the input to an amp.  (some headphones are more difficult to drive than others, and pretty much all are more difficult than an amp input)

Comment: I think I got it. Should know more tomorrow or Saturday at which time I will post. It's great to meet nice people. Thanks!